How to Convert SVG Icon String to React Component in WordPress?
I'm working on a WordPress project where I allow users to select SVG icons from a set. After an icon is selected, its SVG markup is stored in the Redux store as a string.
I need to render this stored SVG string as a React component on the page. How can I convert the SVG string back into a React component to display the selected icon?
Here’s what I have so far:
Storing SVG as a string: The SVG markup is stored in the Redux store.
Rendering the SVG: I need a way to convert this SVG string back into a React component so I can display it properly.
What’s the best approach to achieve this in a React environment?
The selected SVG icon is stored in the Redux store as a string. I have successfully converted this SVG string to an object, but now I need to convert it into a React component to display on the page.
I've tried using React.createElement to render the SVG, but I’m looking for an alternative method. What other ways can an SVG string or object be converted into a React component?
// in state it will store the string of icons like 
{"type":"svg","key":null,"ref":null,"props":{"xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","width":"1em","height":"1em","viewBox":"0 0 24 24","children":{"type":"path","key":null,"ref":null,"props":{"fill":"currentColor","d":"M1 19V5h2v14zm3 0V5h2v14zm3 0V5h1v14zm3 0V5h2v14zm3 0V5h3v14zm4 0V5h1v14zm3 0V5h3v14z"},"_owner":null}},"_owner":null}

Below are simple test code
import {useState} from '@wordpress/element';
 const [selectedIcon, setSelectedIcon] = useState();

<Button onClick={() => setIsOpenModal(true)}>icons</Button>

Now instead of icons in the button, I want to render the SVG icons.
Reminder: I got a bunch of icons and getting them dynamically.

To render an SVG string in React, use the react-svg library. Add library:
npm install react-svg
How use the ReactSVG component:
import { ReactSVG } from 'react-svg';

const MyComponent = () => {
    const svgString = '<svg>...</svg>'; // Your SVG string

    return (
        <ReactSVG src={`data:image/svg+xml;utf8,${encodeURIComponent(svgString)}`} />
    );
};


First of all, I would like to thank you for your response. But, I am getting Svg code like {"type" : "svg", "key": "null", "prop" : {}} and inside of props i have path of svg as i have shown in my quesition the state holds these values so i do not have proper svg tag or somthing like that. And the way you did, I tired it as well but it is creating an empty div.
